# Finding the maximum element in a Binary tree using an inorder traversal

Tags: c, data-structures

```
void inorder(struct btnode *t)
{
    if (root == NULL)
    {
        printf("No elements in a tree to display");
        return;
    }
    max=t->value;
    if (t->l != NULL) 
    {
    inorder(t->l);
    if(max<t->value)
        {
        max=t->value;   
        }
    }   

    if (t->r != NULL)    
    {
    inorder(t->l);
    if(max<t->value)
        {
        max=t->value;   
        }
    }   
    printf("max=%d\n",max);
}
```

I am trying to implement an inorder traversal to find the maximum element in a binary tree. The code that I have written doesn't seem to return a result. By the way, the max variable i used, was declared as a global variable and initialized at zero. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong here? Thank you before hand!

Comment: Max is initialized as zero .

Comment: 1) Expand on "doesn't seem to return a result" 2) Are you successful at printing the BST - do we know it is constructed correctly?  3) Is `max` and `int`?

Comment: isn't it in the definition of a binary tree that the maximum value is all the way on the *right*? But it looks like you `max=t->value;` just after the `if (root == NULL)` block is causing the problems.

Comment: @Davidvanrijn That is true for a binary search tree. I am trying to implement this on a normal binary tree.

Comment: Please clarify your question. "Doesn't seem to return a result" isn't very clear. What doesn't return a result? Your function has a void return (I know you don't mean that but just pointing out that the statement is unclear). Ideally a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should be provided.

Comment: @chux Yes, the Binary Tree prints out properly.

Comment: @AlanAu By not returning a result, I mean that when I execute the program and try to get the max, it stops working.

Comment: @Module I'm not trying to be difficult, but really you need to be more precise in your descriptions. "Stops working" could mean many things. Crashes? Hangs with an infinete loop? Returns but does not print what you want? Prints the wrong max? ...?

Comment: @AlanAu As I said in my previous comment, it stops working (crashes).

Answer (score 3):

`max=t->value;` sets value with no condition.  [@David van rijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4313775/david-van-rijn)

```
void inorder(const struct btnode *t) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        printf("No elements in a tree to display");
        return;
    }
    if(max<t->value) {  // Add test
      max=t->value;
    }
    if (t->l != NULL) {
      inorder(t->l);
    }   
    if (t->r != NULL) {
      // inorder(t->l);  Wrong leaf.
      inorder(t->r);
    }   
    // Best to print from calling routine
    // printf("max=%d\n",max);
}

void foo(const struct btnode *t) {
  max = INT_MIN;  // Set to minimum `int` value.
  inorder(t);
  printf("max=%d\n",max);
}
```

---

OP mentioned that code crashes.  Certainly this was because of the wrong leaf was traversed in `if (t->r != NULL) { inorder(t->l);` and `t->l` was `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you chux. The test should have come at the top before the recursive call of inorder. Thank you once again. I appreciate your help!

Comment: There is just one little problem with the foo function. When I added it to my program, I prints out the max value numerous times (the number of elements in the tree times).

Comment: @Module 1) It makes no _functional_ difference where the `if(max<t->value) {   max=t->value;  }` within `inorder()`  it could be after checking the children or before..  2) Consider  returning the `max` value rather than using a global.  3) Did you remove (comment out) `printf("max=%d\n",max);` from `inorder()`?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to remove it . Now it works fine. Thank you. One more question: If I want to do the same thing but this time using either the postorder or preorder traversal; I could follow the same procedure right?

Comment: @Module Yes.  Also consider small re-write: Let `inorder()` take care of initialization, the empty tree case and print-out.  That function could call `inorder_helper()` which in turn recurses to `inorder_helper()`.  Confident that `inorder_helper()` would be a small recursive function.